# XPath: How to select node with some attribute by index?

Tags: xpath

I have several nodes with some particular attribute and I need to select one of them by index. For example I need to select second `<div>` with 'test' class - `//div[@class='test'][2]` doesn't work.

Is there a way to select node with some attribute by index ? How to do it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**This is a FAQ**.

In XPath the `[]` operator has a higher precedence (binds stronger) than the `//` pseudo-operator.

Because of this, the expression:

```
//div[@class='test'][2]
```

selects all `div` elements whose `class` attribute is "test" and who (the `div` elements) are the second such `div` child of their parent. This is not what you want.

**Use**:

```
(//div[@class='test'])[2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe per XML specification, attributes are not considered to have an order.
`Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant.`
See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags)
I think you'd be best of re-factoring your structure such that attribute order does not describe anything.  If you can give any more details we might be able to offer suggestions.

EDIT: Re-reading your post, looks like you are trying to find node order and not attribute order.  Node order is allowed and your syntax looks OK off-hand.  What software are you doing this in?

Comment: It was my fault - parser hid tags. I've added proper formating.

I use PHP DOM extension http://ua.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and it seems this extension provides weak implementation of XPath

Comment: Did you try  
`//div[@class='test'][position()=2]`