# XSLT and position()

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have

```
<xsl:for-each select="//article[articletype/@id=15 and position() =1]">
```

which pulls back nothing. I then change it to

```
<xsl:for-each select="//article[articletype/@id=15]">
<p><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></p>
```

which pulls back

> 1 2 3 4

Any reason why this is happening? I've even tried `number(position())`. It only works if I use a large numbers and not the position I'm expecting

```
<xsl:for-each select="//article[articletype/@id=15 and position() &lt; 100]">
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate. Consider of having a look @Dimitre answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818681/xpath-how-to-select-node-with-some-attribute-by-index).

Answer (score 5):

This question reduces to: what does `//article[1]` mean? The answer is that it means

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::article[1]
```

which selects the first "article" child of every node in the document. This is different from `(//article)[1]`, which selects the first article in the document.

So the expression you want is

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//article[articletype/@id=15])[1]">
```

Answer (score 0):

With the first XPath you listed: `//article[articletype/@id=15 and position() =1]`, you are asking for the first `article` element at every axis (in document order) that must have an `articletype/@id=15`.

For each axis, if the first `article` element does not have an `articletype` element with `@id=15`, then nothing matches.

With the second XPath: `//article[articletype/@id=15]` you are asking for all of the `article` elements that have an `articletype` child that has `@id=15`.  Apparently, there are 4 of them in your document.

**You should use the following XPath:**

```
(//article[articletype/@id=15])[1]
```

[Dr. Michael Kay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395626/xslt-and-position/6408389#6408389) better explains why it behaves this way.  Also refer to [this answer from Dimitri Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818681/xpath-how-to-select-node-with-some-attribute-by-index/5818966#5818966)

Comment: The suggested expression is correct but the explanation is not: in particular the sentence "you are asking for the first article element (in document order) that must have an articletype/@id=15." is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want the following xpath expression:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//article[articletype/@id=15][1]">
```

Comment: Hmm, even if I want to loop through all of them, using `<xsl:for-each select="//article[articletype/@id=15]">` doesn't work