# How to get the last child node specific element value in xslt?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a xml as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <InsertConcurSAE_batch_req xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>1</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>1</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-07-31</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>7</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>90.9900</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>90.9900</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>90.9900</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>90.9900</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+90.9900</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>34</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>1</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>90.9900</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>90.9900</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>2</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>5</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-08-02</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>9</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>138.6700</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>138.6700</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>138.6700</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>138.6700</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+138.6700</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>35</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>5</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>138.6700</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>138.6700</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>3</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>6</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-08-03</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>4</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>26.9500</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>26.9500</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>26.9500</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>26.9500</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+26.9500</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>36</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>6</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>26.9500</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>26.9500</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>4</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>7</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-08-07</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>6</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>57.8100</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>57.8100</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>57.8100</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>57.8100</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+57.8100</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>37</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>7</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>57.8100</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>57.8100</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
        </InsertConcurSAE_batch_req>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to get the last sequence_number i.e., 4.

I have the following xslt to retrieve but it doesnt show any value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"><xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//InsertConcurSAE[last()]">

                <xsl:variable name="sequence_number" select="//dat:sequence_number" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$sequence_number" />
            </xsl:for-each> 

    </ns:text>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

please help me out to fix this issue. If I place

```
<xsl:for-each select="*">
```

instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="//InsertConcurSAE[last()]">
```

then it only results with 1.I need to retrieve the last sequence_number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/*/dat:InsertConcurSAE[last()]/dat:sequence_number/text()
```

**Here is a complete verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/*/*/dat:InsertConcurSAE[last()]
                 /dat:sequence_number/text()"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <InsertConcurSAE_batch_req xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>1</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>1</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-07-31</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>7</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>90.9900</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>90.9900</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>90.9900</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>90.9900</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+90.9900</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>34</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>1</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>90.9900</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>90.9900</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>2</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>5</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-08-02</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>9</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>138.6700</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>138.6700</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>138.6700</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>138.6700</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+138.6700</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>35</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>5</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>138.6700</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>138.6700</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>3</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>6</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-08-03</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>4</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>26.9500</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>26.9500</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>26.9500</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>26.9500</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+26.9500</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>36</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>6</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>26.9500</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>26.9500</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
            <InsertConcurSAE>
                <constant>DETAIL</constant>
                <batch_id>6</batch_id>
                <batch_date>2012-08-13</batch_date>
                <sequence_number>4</sequence_number>
                <emp_id>8535</emp_id>
                <last_name>Burson</last_name>
                <first_name>Sherrie</first_name>
                <group_id>US</group_id>
                <employee_org_unit_1>30</employee_org_unit_1>
                <employee_org_unit_2>80</employee_org_unit_2>
                <employee_org_unit_3>500</employee_org_unit_3>
                <employee_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</employee_org_unit_4>
                <report_id>4CDF6336F5C947E2A0F8</report_id>
                <report_key>1</report_key>
                <ledger>SEMTECH</ledger>
                <reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>USD</reimburse_currency_alpha_ise>
                <home_country>UNITED STATES</home_country>
                <report_submit_date>2012-08-08</report_submit_date>
                <report_user_defined_date>2012-08-01</report_user_defined_date>
                <report_payment_processing_date>2012-08-10</report_payment_processing_date>
                <report_name>August</report_name>
                <report_image_required>Y</report_image_required>
                <report_has_vat_entry>N</report_has_vat_entry>
                <report_has_ta_entry>N</report_has_ta_entry>
                <report_total_post_amount>314.4200</report_total_post_amount>
                <report_total_approved_amount>314.4200</report_total_approved_amount>
                <report_policy_name>Non VAT Expense Policy</report_policy_name>
                <report_org_unit_1>30</report_org_unit_1>
                <report_org_unit_2>99</report_org_unit_2>
                <report_org_unit_3>500</report_org_unit_3>
                <report_org_unit_4>G&amp;A Function</report_org_unit_4>
                <report_custom_1>G&amp;A Function</report_custom_1>
                <report_custom_15>US</report_custom_15>
                <report_custom_16>8535</report_custom_16>
                <report_custom_17>N02574</report_custom_17>
                <report_custom_18>46</report_custom_18>
                <report_custom_19>1402</report_custom_19>
                <report_custom_20>BE1</report_custom_20>
                <entry_id>7</entry_id>
                <entry_transaction_type>REG</entry_transaction_type>
                <expense_type>D-Business Meal with attendees</expense_type>
                <entry_transaction_date>2012-08-07</entry_transaction_date>
                <spend_currency_alpha_iso>USD</spend_currency_alpha_iso>
                <currency_exchange_rate>1.0000</currency_exchange_rate>
                <exchange_rate_direction>M</exchange_rate_direction>
                <is_personal>N</is_personal>
                <receipt_received>N</receipt_received>
                <receipt_type>N</receipt_type>
                <total_employee_attendee>6</total_employee_attendee>
                <report_entry_custom_1>No</report_entry_custom_1>
                <report_entry_custom_35>US</report_entry_custom_35>
                <report_entry_custom_39>0.0000</report_entry_custom_39>
                <report_entry_custom_40>57.8100</report_entry_custom_40>
                <entry_transaction_amount>57.8100</entry_transaction_amount>
                <entry_posted_amount>57.8100</entry_posted_amount>
                <entry_approved_amount>57.8100</entry_approved_amount>
                <entry_payment_code>CASH</entry_payment_code>
                <entry_payment_code_name>Cash</entry_payment_code_name>
                <entry_country>US</entry_country>
                <entry_country_sub>US-CA</entry_country_sub>
                <domestic_foreign>HOME</domestic_foreign>
                <payer_pay_type>Company</payer_pay_type>
                <payer_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payer_pay_code>
                <payee_pay_type>Employee</payee_pay_type>
                <payee_pay_code>Company/Employee Pseudo Payment Code</payee_pay_code>
                <account_code>70210</account_code>
                <drcr>DR</drcr>
                <journal_amount>+57.8100</journal_amount>
                <journal_key>37</journal_key>
                <allocation_alloc_key>7</allocation_alloc_key>
                <allocation_percentage>100.0000</allocation_percentage>
                <report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_tax_posted_amount>
                <net_tax_amount>57.8100</net_tax_amount>
                <report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>0.0000</report_entry_total_reclaim_adjusted_amount>
                <net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>57.8100</net_adjusted_reclaim_amount>
                <payment_type>Out of Pocket</payment_type>
            </InsertConcurSAE>
        </InsertConcurSAE_batch_req>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
4
```

Comment: The above transformation works fine.But when I run it through the WSO2 sequence it is throws error since it is not able to evaluate the XPath expression "/*/*/*".So I need to define the XPath.

Comment: Hey.Thanks for the help.I placed the below line                                                                  `//dat:InsertConcurSAE_batch_req/dat:InsertConcurSAE[last()]/dat:sequence_number`                                                  instead of `/*/*/*/dat:InsertConcurSAE[last()]/dat:sequence_number/text()`    and it worked.Thanks once again

Comment: @user1662039, You are welcome. The expression you used worked only by chance. A correct expression is (note the brackets): `(//someExpr)[last()]`. See this answer for detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5818966/36305 . Also, avoid using `//` whenever the structure of the XML document is known in advance. `//` can be *very slow*.

Comment: @user1662039, Continued: It is generally much faster to specify a full path leading to the wanted nodes. The fact that you were not able to use my XPath expression directly, means that the structure (number of levels to the nodes , etc) of your real XML document is different from the one that I used in this answer. Simply find the correct *full* XPath expression that selects the wanted nodes in *that* document -- and use this XPath expression.