# What is the XPath expression to find only the first occurrence?

Tags: xml, xpath, expression

I used this Xpath expression `"//span[@class='Big']"` and got all elements in that page that are under `<span>` tag and `class='Big'`.

My question is what if I want just the first occurrence on the page, not all occurrences, what would be the correct `Xpath` expression?

Thanks,
Narin

Answer (score 162, accepted):

**The correct answer (note the brackets)**:

```
(//span[@class='Big'])[1]
```

**The following expression is wrong in the general case:**

```
//span[@class='Big'][1]
```

because it selects every `span` element in the document, that satisfies the condition in the first predicate, and that is *the first such child of its parent* -- there can be many such elements in an XML document and all of them will be selected.

For more detailed explanation see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818966/36305

Comment: This method is not working for Appium. //android.view.View[contains(@text,'Sapiens A Brief History of Humankind Paperback English')] matches with 2 elements, but (//android.view.View[contains(@text,'Sapiens A Brief History of Humankind Paperback English')])[0] does locate any element..

Comment: Actualy i made a mistake, it works, My index value was wrong (index starts from 1 and not 0)

Comment: Thanks, I actually needed the second method for my situation. I appreciate you pointing out the difference!

Answer (score 7):

Dimitre Novatchev's answer is correct if you are expecting the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute to be ***equal to*** `Big` (without any other classes attached to the element):

```
(//span[@class="Big"])[1]
```

... which is similar to the following JavaScript expression:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span[class="Big"]')[0]
```

---

On the other hand, if you are expecting `Big` to be ***one of any number*** of classes in the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) attribute (rather than the only class), you can use the following expression:

```
(//span[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " Big ")])[1]
```

... which is similar to the following JavaScript expression:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span.Big')[0]
```