# Java XPATH select only the first element of child

Tags: java, xpath

My sample input XML is:

```
<root>
    <a>
    <b>
    <c>item1</c>
    <d>item2</d>
    <e>item3</e> 
    </b>
    </a>
    <a>
    <b>
    <c>item4</c>
    <c>item5</c>
    <e>item6</e>   
    </b>        
    </a>
    </root>
```

I am suppose to select all the first occurrence of node c.
The output should be item1 and item4.
when I am using /root/a/b/c it returns item1,item4 and item5.

Comment: Try `/root/a/b/c[0]`. Otherwise show some more of what you're trying (e.g. code).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the XPath expression to find only the first occurrence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294997/what-is-the-xpath-expression-to-find-only-the-first-occurrence)

Comment: where tag `b` is closing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294997/what-is-the-xpath-expression-to-find-only-the-first-occurrence here only the first element is selected.I want to select all the first occurrence of node c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this for your example `//root//c[1]` and it's working as you expect.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
/root/a/b/c[1]
```

For more detailed explanation see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818966/36305

Comment: It gives only the first occurrence that is item1 and not item4.