# Xpath expression pulling multiple items despite specifying item with [ ]

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to write an XPath expression which can return the URL associated with the next page of a search.

The URL which leads to the next page of the search is always the `href` in the `a` tag following the tag `span class="navCurrentPage"` I have been trying to use a `following-sibling` term to pull the next URL.  My search in the Chrome console is:

```
$x('//span[@class="navCurrentPage"][1]/following-sibling::a/@href[1]')
```

I thought by specifying `@href[1]` I would only get back one URL (thinking the [1] chooses the first element in list), but instead Chrome (and Scrapy) are returning four URLs. I don't understand why. Please help me to understand how to select the one URL that I am looking for.

Here is the URL where you can find the HTML giving me trouble:

https://www.yachtworld.com/core/listing/cache/searchResults.jsp?cit=true&slim=quick&ybw=&sm=3&searchtype=advancedsearch&Ntk=boatsEN&Ntt=&is=false&man=&hmid=102&ftid=101&enid=0&type=%28Sail%29&fromLength=35&toLength=50&fromYear=1985&toYear=2010&fromPrice=&toPrice=&luom=126&currencyid=100&city=&rid=100&rid=101&rid=104&rid=105&rid=107&rid=108&rid=112&rid=114&rid=115&rid=116&rid=128&rid=130&rid=153&pbsint=&boatsAddedSelected=-1

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence: `//x[1]` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::x[1]` which finds every descendant `x` that is the first child of its parent. You want `(//x)[1]` which finds the first node among all the descendants named `x`.

Comment: Thanks. This syntax works within scrapy and the chrome console. If you can clarify how the brackets work within xpath expressions it would be a big help.  Chrome seems to use them extensively when identifying elements (for instance, the following xpath is provided by chrome when identifying the individual element:    "//*[@id="searchResultsHeader"]/div[1]/span[3]/a[1]" I'm not sure why these brackets are valid and my code's are not.

Comment: That example doesn't use a numeric predicate in a step starting with "//", which is where the complications in your example arise. See the note under bullet item 3 in the spec §3.3.5: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#abbrev

Answer (score 0):

xpath index will apply on all matching records, if you want to get only the first item, get the first instance.

```
$x('//span[@class="navCurrentPage"][1]/following-sibling::a/@href[1]').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 0):

just add, .extract_first() or .get() to fetch the first item.

see the scrapy documentation [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've found this very helpful to make sure you have the bracket in the right place.
[What is the XPath expression to find only the first occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294997/what-is-the-xpath-expression-to-find-only-the-first-occurrence)
also, the first occurrence may be [0] not [1]