# How to embed links within a likert plot, separate links for each likert item

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I'm trying to embed hyperlinks within a plot of likert data, using a  combination of the likert package and the gridSVG packages. I want to link the text of each question to a separate link, but I'm having problems. The following code embeds a single link to the text of every question, but I can't figure-out how to embed on each question separately, because the set of questions seem to be grouped in a single grob together. Thanks in advance for your input.

```
#creates an example plot from sample data from likert package.
require(likert) 
data(pisaitems)
items29 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) ==  "ST25Q" ]
names(items29) <- c("Magazines", "Comic books", "Fiction",
               "Non-fiction books", "Newspapers")
l29 <- likert(items29)
summary(l29)
plot(l29)

require(grid)
require(gridSVG)

#identifies grob of question text (all questions are in a single grob)
titleGrobName <- grep("axis-l.3-3-3-3", grid.ls(print=FALSE)$name, value=TRUE)

#embeds link in grob
grid.hyperlink(titleGrobName, "http://www.r-project.org")

#creates svg
gridToSVG("testPlot.svg", "none", "none")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This grouped `GROB` is not uncommon.  Since I don't think we want to rewrite `likert` to ungroup these, we might be better off by manipulating the `SVG` after `grid` with `XML`.  Here is one way of accomplishing this.

[live example](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/raw/86df2d60c08fc1217d75/)

We could also add the links on the `HTML/JavaScript` side if you expect this graphic to be part of a bigger web page.

```
#creates an example plot from sample data from likert package.
require(likert) 
data(pisaitems)
items29 <- pisaitems[,substr(names(pisaitems), 1,5) ==  "ST25Q" ]
names(items29) <- c("Magazines", "Comic books", "Fiction",
                    "Non-fiction books", "Newspapers")
l29 <- likert(items29)
summary(l29)
plot(l29)

# if possible to use htmltools from RStudio
#   install.packages("htmltools")
#  then we can add the links on the
#  XML side instead of in grid
library(XML)
library(htmltools)
library(gridSVG)

# export as XML SVG
likert_svg <- grid.export("", addClasses=TRUE)$svg

# find our axes
nodes <- getNodeSet(
  likert_svg,
  # thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818681/xpath-how-to-select-node-with-some-attribute-by-index
  "(//x:g[contains(@id,'axis')])[1]//x:tspan",
  "x"
)

lapply(
  nodes,
  function(node){
    # get the text value of the node
    lbl = xmlValue(node)
    # remove the text from our node
    xmlValue(node) <- ""

    # create a <a href=> hyperlink
    #  https://www.w3.org/wiki/SVG_Links
    a_node <- newXMLNode(
      "a",
      #######   change your link here ###########
      attrs = c("xlink:href"=paste0("http://google.com/search?q=",lbl)),
      lbl
    )
    # add our new linked text to the node
    addChildren(node, a_node)
  }
)


# look at it in the browser/RStudio Viewer
browsable(
  HTML(
    saveXML(
      #  export as SVG XML
      likert_svg,
      prefix = ""
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: timelyportfolio's javascript example appears to work. Thanks!

Comment: The example does appear to work, but how do export the resulting svg file with the linked axis labels? In the example the resulting svg opens in a browser, which appears to be living in a temporary folder, but how can I do the manipulation and then export the resulting svg with the linked axis (like I did when I previously exported "testPlot.svg")? I tried adding a file name to the `grid.export("", addClasses=TRUE)$svg` part of the example code, which did create an svg file, but it did not have the live links. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `saveXML` will give you what you want (see http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xml/docs/saveXML).  You can eliminate the `prefix=""` if you want a full XML, and if you want a file you can specify `file = "mysvg.svg"`.


`saveXML(likert_svg, prefix = "" )`